# CouchDB, limit creating users to admins only

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm working on a CouchDB backend that will exist as a central store for a React app using PouchDB. Reading the docs on the security section: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/security.html, one does not need an admin account or a user account of any kind to create user records. Now, they wouldn't be able to create any documents, as I have admin party disabled. But I also don't want an open API end point to allow just anyone to write data. Is there a way for me to restrict this?

I've tried to see if I could setup a security document like so:

```
curl -X PUT http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/_users/_security -d '{"admins":{"names":[],"roles":[]},"members":{"names":[],"roles":[]}}'
```

But I'm still able to add users:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:abc1 -d '{"name":"abc1", "password":"abc1", "roles":[], "type":"user"}'
```

Is there something I can change so I cannot do a put request to the `couchdb.users` namespace without admin credentials?

Comment: from the top of my head, I guess you need at least one name or role to actually be admin

Comment: Gave that a try, unfortunately it still lets me write users without admin credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting no admins or users in your security document and a database with no members allows any user to write regular documents, same as default behaviour.

Try to set your server's admin as `_users` database admin, i.e. change the security document to `-d '{"admins": { "names": ["admin"], "roles": [] }, "members": { "names": [], "roles": [] }}'` or even better create an admin role and assign it to a separate CouchDB user for more granular control.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave this a try already as suggested by Sebastion in my question comments, but no luck. I am using couchdb 2.0.0, in case that might make a difference.

Comment: It might, actually, a lot of things changed between 1.x an 2.x. I suspect it now expects at least one user or role in a members section to restrict an  anonymous access. Try to set the security object to `{"admins": {"roles": ["_admin"]}, "members": {"roles": ["_admin"]}}`, this is the default security object for new databases when a configuration parameter "default_security" in a section "[couchdb]" set to "admin_only".